# reducing noise in semi gloss metal - is there a material specific option to reduce noise?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm a total nube to Blender just starting to learn the basics.

I wanted to know if there any material specific settings to reduce noise of a particular material.

Like the semiglossy metallic material on the left of this Cycles render:

[image: Test render in cycles]

The semiglossy red sphere on right does not bother me as much as the noisy metallic sphere on left - and would like to increase the quality of that specific metallic material.

Comment: You could try turning down the bounces of glossy materials in the render settings... But that might result in loss of realism

Comment: Thanks for your replies - I am not asking about global noise reduction - but material specific control - is there any way to do it in Blender/Cycles?